# How is total raw calculated for Science Pack 2?

Tags: factorio

I don't understand how the total resource needed is calculated to produce one Science pack 2 (green one).

According to the [Factorio wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Science_pack_2),
Science pack 2 requires:

- 1 Inserter
- 1 Transport belt

**Calculation for one Inserter**

According to the [Factorio wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Inserter)
an Inserter requires:

- 1 Green circuit
- 1 Iron gear
- **1 Iron plate**

According to the [Factorio wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Electronic_circuit)
a Green circuit requires:

- 3 Copper cables
- **1 Iron plate**

According to the [Factorio wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Iron_gear_wheel)
an Iron gear requires:

- **2 Iron plates**

According to the [Factorio wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Copper_cable)
Copper cable requires (to produce 2):

- 1 Copper plate **(1.5 Copper plate to produce 3 units)**

So, to produce 1 Inserter, we need 4 Iron plates + 1.5 Copper plates.

---

**Calculation for Transport belt**

According to the [Factorio wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Transport_belt)
a Transport belt requires:

- 1 Iron gear ( requires  **2 Iron plates** )
- **1 Iron plate**

So, to produce 1 Transport belt, we need 3 Iron plates.

---

Then, to produce one Science Pack 2, we need 7 Iron plates and 1.5 Copper plates.

Why is the total raw 5.5 Iron plates and 1.5 Copper plates?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The recipe for transport belts makes two belts, not one